# jQuery: binding events on tab change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events

My page contains 3 tabs, with a **common.js**, and **tab1n3.js** (for 1st and 3rd tab behavior) and **tab2.js** for (2nd tab behavior).

Events work fine after page refresh but stop working after tab change. I've inspected that events are not getting bind on tab change. I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('click', '.selector', function() {..});
});

$("#tabs").on( "tabsactivate", function(event, ui) {
        $(document).on('click', '.selector', function() { .. });
//      also this
//      $('.selector').click(function() {..});
    });
```

and

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.selector').click(function() {..});
});
```

but none of these binds events at tab change. Please help!

Comment: try the `active` event

Comment: Replace `activate` with `active`

Comment: can you add a fiddle ?